# get document´s id // php-javascript

Tags: javascript, php, document

so here is a html-list of my documents:

```
<form action="submitPage.html" method="post" onsubmit="submit();">
<img id="img1" src="inventory_images/berg.jpg" onclick="changeColor(this, 1);" />
<img id="img2" src="inventory_images/berg.jpg" onclick="changeColor(this, 2);" />
```

and JavaScript code, is used:

```
<script>
markedImage = 0; // The variable used for the submit;
function unmarkAll() {   
document.getElementById("img1").style.borderColor = "#000000";
document.getElementById("img2").style.borderColor = "#000000";
}
function changeColor(obj, markedId) {
unmarkAll();
obj.style.borderColor  ="#00FF00";
markedImage = markedId;
}
</script>
<script>
function submit()
{
    document.getElementById("markedImage").value = markedImage;
}
</script>
```

So, the user has the possibilty to select one picture and click "submit".
Then he will be directed to "submitPage.html" :

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
?>
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = "POST") {
    echo "Variables coming<br />";
} else {
    die("No Post Variables");
}
if ($_POST['markedImage'] = "POST") {
echo "Picture has been chosen<br />";
echo "This one:<br />";
$picture_id = $_POST['markedImage'];
echo $picture_id;
} else {
    echo "FAIL";
}
?>
```

I just want to display the "id" of the chosen image. ( display "img1" or "img2" )
What should i change?
greetings

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<form action="submitPage.html" method="post" onsubmit="submit();">
<img id="img1" src="inventory_images/berg.jpg" onclick="changeColor(this, 1);" />
<img id="img2" src="inventory_images/berg.jpg" onclick="changeColor(this, 2);" />
```

try

```
<form action="submitPage.html" method="post" onsubmit="submit();">
<img id="img1" src="inventory_images/berg.jpg" onclick="changeColor(this.id, 1);" />
<img id="img2" src="inventory_images/berg.jpg" onclick="changeColor(this.id, 2);" />
```

so markedId will actually be the image id.

Comment: <form action="submitPage.html" method="post" onsubmit="submit();"><img id="img1" src="inventory_images/berg.jpg" onclick="changeColor(this.id, 1);" />
      <img id="img2" src="inventory_images/berg.jpg" onclick="changeColor(this.id, 2);" /><input type="hidden" id="markedImage" name="markedImage" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" /></form>

Comment: my js-code: <script>
markedImage = 0; 
function unmarkAll() {
    document.getElementById("img1").style.borderColor = "#000000"; 
    document.getElementById("img2").style.borderColor = "#000000";
    document.getElementById("img3").style.borderColor = "#000000";
    document.getElementById("img4").style.borderColor = "#000000";
}
function changeColor(obj, markedId) {
unmarkAll();
obj.style.borderColor  ="#00FF00";
markedImage = markedId;
}
</script>
<script>
function submit()
{
    document.getElementById("markedImage").value = markedImage;
}
</script>

Comment: my submitPage.html : <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    ?>
    <?php
    $picture_id = $_POST['markedImage'];
    echo $picture_id;
    ?>                  Now i even cant chose an image with my function changeColor. I just want to display the id of the chose image, what do i have to change?

Comment: which part didn't work? add alert(markedId); as the first line of code in your changeColor function. if the call this.id then you should be getting the image id.